# bcrypt compareSync "Unhandled rejection Error: data and hash must be strings"

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, bcrypt, knex.js

I'm using knex to select a specific users password from my database. this hashed password is returned to me in an object like this:

```
[ anonymous {
 password_hash: 
 '$2a$10$zRSFdNJsg8S3Xv1I73gjYuRu.Mw/9Dtujh0dTqrtc9DA12vUHuqbK' } ]
```

When I try using `bcrypt.compareSync` to compare the entered password and the password that exists in the database, it give me an error saying data and hash must be strings. I tried using the `.toString()` method and `JSON.stringify(password_hash)`. But both don't help. How do I get this to work?

Here is my code:

```
knex('users').where({
    email: req.body.loginEmail
  }).select('password_hash')
  .then(function(password_hash) {
      //console.log("resp", password_hash)
      console.log("JSON stringifies",JSON.stringify(password_hash))
      console.log("req", req.body.loginPass)
      console.log('hash', password_hash)
      bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.loginPass, JSON.stringify(password_hash), function(err, doesMatch){
      if (doesMatch){
        console.log("Passwords Match")
        req.session.email = rows[0].email;
        var templateVars = {
          emale: req.session.email
        }
        res.render('/dashboard', templateVars)
      } else {
        console.log("THIS IS THE ERROR", err);
        res.send("I DONT KNOW YOU. SIGN UP FIRSt.")
      }
    })
  })
```

My entire error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: data and hash must be strings
at Object.compareSync (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:144:15)
at /vagrant/CaloBoxInc/server.js:159:14
at tryCatcher (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/vagrant/CaloBoxInc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:570:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:550:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:529:5)
```

Comment: Could you add complete testcase for example with runkit, which reproduces your problem?

Comment: pls, update your question with full code.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your `req.body.loginPass` is not string? `JSON.stringify` always returns undefined / string and bcrypt returns different error if parameter is undefined so that paramater can't be the problem.

Try force casting `req.body.loginPass` to string like this:

```
bcrypt.compareSync(´´+ req.body.loginPass, ...
```

(just for debugging purposes... though you should already see from earlier console logs it it is not a string).

Comment: I tried it... still getting the same error. Instead of rendering, I even tried redirecting, but thats of no help either...

Answer (score 0):

This error arises if one or more arguments passed to `bcrypt.compareSync` function are either undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is by changing the datatype of the password field in your Database to char(150) to avoid truncation. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your mongoose file, where you can set your types of email and password. Change type of password from `Number` to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

In the database, the older password value was not a hashed password. It was in a String. Delete the old value in the database. Create a new one with the hashed password and then validate it. It works.